# Convert a Oracle style join to ANSI SQL Join

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access

I have this query for an oracle Database, I'm accessing it using MS Access via ODBC.

This query does not work on access I need to convert it in a standard SQL,I have tried several time with no success. I would like to know if could help me out thanks!

```
   select t2.s_studentreference "Ad No"
        , t1.p_surname "Surname"
        , t1.p_forenames "Forenames"
        , t3.e_reference "Reference"
        , t3.e_name "Name" 
    from capd_a t2
       , capd_b t1
       , capd_c t3 
   where t2.s_id(+)=t1.p_id 
     and (t3.e_student=t1.p_id) 
     and (t3.e_reference='D /YR2A2/12')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by `standard SQL` you mean `ANSI SQL` then your query might look like this

```
   select t2.s_studentreference "Ad No"
        , t1.p_surname "Surname"
        , t1.p_forenames "Forenames"
        , t3.e_reference "Reference"
        , t3.e_name "Name" 
    from capd_b t1
   right outer join capd_a t2
      on (t2.s_id = t1.p_id)
    join capd_c t3 
      on ((t3.e_student=t1.p_id) and (t3.e_reference='D /YR2A2/12'))
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, I will test it in few minutes and accept it asap. Thanks